# Remove repeated content Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, hashset, filewriter

I got this text, and I need to filter out these repeated lines and words.
I don't know if there's a better way than what I'm doing.

```
00:00:00,413|03:50:25,600|ISDB|>> FALAM QUE A GENTE COMBINA
00:00:00,413|03:50:25,600|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU
00:00:01,135|00:00:01,315|ISDB|>> FALAM QUE A GENTE COMBINA
00:00:01,135|00:00:01,315|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:01,315|00:00:02,218|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:01,315|00:00:02,218|ISDB|BOBAS PARA
00:00:02,218|00:00:02,398|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:02,218|00:00:02,398|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS
00:00:02,398|00:00:02,759|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:02,398|00:00:02,759|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO
00:00:02,759|00:00:03,274|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:02,759|00:00:03,274|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV?
00:00:03,274|00:00:04,357|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV?
00:00:03,274|00:00:04,357|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A?
00:00:04,357|00:00:05,259|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV?
00:00:04,357|00:00:05,259|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A? ELES
00:00:05,259|00:00:05,414|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A? ELES
00:00:05,414|00:00:05,775|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A? ELES
00:00:05,414|00:00:05,775|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS
00:00:05,775|00:00:06,677|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A? ELES
00:00:05,775|00:00:06,677|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO
00:00:06,677|00:00:06,858|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A? ELES
00:00:06,677|00:00:06,858|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL
00:00:06,858|03:50:32,400|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL DE
00:00:06,858|03:50:32,400|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT?QUE
00:00:07,914|00:00:07,916|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL DE
00:00:07,914|00:00:07,916|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT?QUE EU
00:00:07,914|00:00:08,997|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT?QUE EU GOSTO
00:00:08,997|00:00:09,178|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT?QUE EU GOSTO
```

And I'm using that code, to put these lines in a HashSet so they don't be repeated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
public class Testecc {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      String filePath = "C://teste//teste1.txt";
      String input = null;
      //Buffered reader
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
      while((input=br.readLine()) !=null){
                input=br.readLine();

      //FileWriter (criando arquivo)
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C://teste//teste.txt");
      //hashset para elimitar duplicatas
      Set set = new HashSet();
      String line;
      //adicionando linhas no hashset
      while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
          String line1= line.substring(0,31);
          String line2=line.substring(31);
          System.out.println(line);
          if(set.add(line2)){

      writer.append(line1+line2+"\n");
          }
      }
      writer.flush();
      System.out.println("Pronto!");
   }
}
   }
```

With this I removed the duplicated lines like this:

```
00:00:01,135|00:00:01,315|ISDB|>> FALAM QUE A GENTE COMBINA
00:00:01,135|00:00:01,315|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:01,315|00:00:02,218|ISDB|BOBAS PARA
00:00:02,218|00:00:02,398|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS
00:00:02,398|00:00:02,759|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO
00:00:02,759|00:00:03,274|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV�S
00:00:03,274|00:00:04,357|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A�.
00:00:04,357|00:00:05,259|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A�. ELES
00:00:05,414|00:00:05,775|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS
00:00:05,775|00:00:06,677|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO
00:00:06,677|00:00:06,858|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL
00:00:06,858|03:50:32,400|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL DE
00:00:06,858|03:50:32,400|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT� QUE
00:00:07,914|00:00:07,916|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT� QUE EU
00:00:07,914|00:00:08,997|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT� QUE EU GOSTO
```

But I also need to remove the repeated words.

I'm really out of ideas.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the rule determining which "duplicate" row gets retained?  I don't see any obvious rule.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But i need to remove the repeated words also."?
That you want to keep "COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL DE" but not "COLOCARAM AS FOTOS", "COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO", ..._

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by 'repeated words', and what do you need to do with the lines, that contain them?

Comment: Also, please use english comments, it helps communicating your intent.

Comment: I need to keep just the last line of that, for exemple:  00:00:01,315|00:00:02,218|ISDB|BOBAS PARA
00:00:02,218|00:00:02,398|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS
00:00:02,398|00:00:02,759|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO
00:00:02,759|00:00:03,274|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV�S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a map which would hold line values grouped by a certain key. A key would a beginning of the line, starting from the words you are interested in, say, first 5 letters. Then add those lines to the map, and if the line is longer than the one found previously, replace it.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath))) {

  final Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  br.lines().forEach(line -> {
        String message = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("|") + 1);
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
          return;
        }
        String key = message.split(" ")[0];
        if (map.get(key) == null) {
          map.put(key, line);
        } else if (map.get(key).length() < line.length()) {
          map.remove(key);
          map.put(key, line);
        }
      }
  );

  map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(v));
}
```

The above code will give you the following output.

```
00:00:00,413|03:50:25,600|ISDB|>> FALAM QUE A GENTE COMBINA
00:00:01,135|00:00:01,315|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:02,759|00:00:03,274|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV?
00:00:04,357|00:00:05,259|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A? ELES
00:00:06,858|03:50:32,400|ISDB|COLOCARAM AS FOTOS COMO PAPEL DE
00:00:07,914|00:00:08,997|ISDB|PAREDE, PARECE AT?QUE EU GOSTO
```

Comment: Your logic which handles the map is superfluous, and you don't need to check for null before inserting.  Just do a put (or see my answer).  In addition, hash maps do NOT maintain insertion order, so the order which your answer prints the logs likely would not be correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right about the order, changed it to LinkedHashMap, thanks for the hint!

Comment: I guess we almost there. But got that error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 31, end 36, length 33"

Comment: You need to handle empty or short messages. Due to lack of data, I can't say what you need to do exactly, but I have tried to generalize the code a bit, please try it.

Comment: Ok, I will try, but not so sure how.

Comment: @RodrigoMarros See the updated code.

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, now it's ok. All working fine. Thanks a lot. Got a lot to study and learn.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the final post-pipe portion of each log line as a key, then insert each line into a `LinkedHashMap`, to remove duplicates:

```
String filePath = "C:/log.txt";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
String input;
Map<String, String> logMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    input = br.readLine();
    String key = input.replaceAll("^.*\\|", "");
    logMap.put(key, input);
}

// Now print out the map minus duplicates
for (String line : logMap.values()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Instead of printing to the console, you could just as easily write the filtered log out to another file.  Note that this approach would retain the *last* occurring line of each duplicate.

Comment: The result was the same: 00:00:00,413|03:50:25,600|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU
00:00:01,135|00:00:01,315|ISDB|PERFEITAMENTE. EU PEDI REVISTAS
00:00:01,315|00:00:02,218|ISDB|BOBAS PARA
00:00:02,218|00:00:02,398|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS
00:00:02,398|00:00:02,759|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO
00:00:02,759|00:00:03,274|ISDB|BOBAS PARA AMIGOS E AO INV�S
00:00:03,274|00:00:04,357|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A�.
00:00:06,677|00:00:06,858|ISDB|DISSO TROUXERAM ISSO A�. ELES